# oracle query to split the example@gmail.com into columns when ever special char is encountered

Tags: oracle

Here i have written code but that contains special characters also.But my requirement is ask for user to give a email dynamically  and split that email when ever special chars occurs with out special characters i need the out put.

```
col1     col2     col3  
------------------

example123  gmail   com
```

---

```
select substr('exapmle123@gmail.com',instr('example123@gmail.com','@'),instr('example123@gmail.com','.')) as col1 ,
     substr('exapmle123@gmail.com',1,instr('example123@gmail.com','@')) as col2,
     substr('exapmle123@gmail.com',instr('example123@gmail.com','.'),length('example123@gmail.com')) as col3 
     from dual;
```

Comment: Define "special characters".  From your output, it appears that you are considering numbers to be "special characters" (example vs example123) which would be a rather unique definition.

Comment: @ , # $ % ^ & * (  ) _ -  . these are special characters not 123's   Thank you

Comment: Then why do you want to return "example" as "col1" when your data is apparently "example123"?

Comment: Oops sorry it's my mistake...  i will edit that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use REGEXP_SUBSTR for splitting strings

**Approach 1**

In the example below, there is a row for every new word and row and colnumbers are part of the resultset. I suggest you to use this approach since you can not know the numbers of words/colummns beforehand

**Query1**

```
with MyString  as
 (          select 'exapmle123@gmail.com' Str, 1 rnum from dual
  )
,pivot as (
  Select Rownum Pnum
  From dual
  Connect By Rownum <= 100   
  )
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (ms.Str,'([[:alnum:]])+',1,pv.pnum), ms.rnum, pv.pnum colnum
  FROM MyString ms
      ,pivot pv
where REGEXP_SUBSTR (ms.Str,'([[:alnum:]])+',1,pv.pnum) is not null
```

**Result1**

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(MS.STR       RNUM     COLNUM
-------------------- ---------- ----------
exapmle123                    1          1
gmail                         1          2
com                           1          3
```

**Approach 2**
If you know how many words/columns you'll have, then you can use

**Query2**

```
with MyString  as
 (          select 'exapmle123@gmail.com' Str, 1 rnum from dual
  )
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (ms.Str,'([[:alnum:]])+',1,1) col1, REGEXP_SUBSTR (ms.Str,'([[:alnum:]])+',1,2) col2, REGEXP_SUBSTR (ms.Str,'([[:alnum:]])+',1,3) col3
  FROM MyString ms
```

**Result2**

```
COL1       COL2  COL
---------- ----- ---
exapmle123 gmail com
```

Comment: Thank You so much  @ Ricardo Amold